# Send signed ints to/from socket

Tags: c

Writing an application which sends 4 ints over socket, trying the following but getting 0s at receiving end...

I assume this is something to do with the way I'm passing them signedness & endianness etc...

```
int _send(int sock, int c, int x, int y, int w)
{
    int cc, xc, yc, wc;
    char buf[16];
    int offset;
    struct sockaddr_in sap;
    char echoBuffer[1];     /* Buffer for echo string */
    int bytesRcvd, totalBytesRcvd;   /* Bytes read in single recv() and total bytes read */

    offset = 0;

    buf[offset] = htonl(c);
    buf[4] = htonl(x);
    buf[8] = htonl(y);
    buf[12] = htonl(w);

    if (send(sock, buf, 16, 0) != 16)
    {
        printf("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
        return(-1);
    }

        //...

}
```

And this is the code at the receiving end:

```
while (listen(sock, 2) == 0)
    {
        printf("listened...\r\n");


            int addrlen;
            struct sockaddr_in address;

            addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
            int channel = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, &addrlen);

            if (channel<0)
            {
                perror("Accept connection");
                return -1;
            }

        else {
            printf("accepted\r\n");

            while (1)
            {

            int size = 16;
            char buffer[16];

            recv( channel, buffer, size, 0);

            for (int i=0; i<=12; i+=4)
            {
                int c = ntohl(buffer[i]);
                printf("%d\r\n", c);
            }
                 }
```

Comment: If it was signedness/byte order, you'd get SOMETHING. A 'corrupted' number if the high/low bytes were swapped, but not just zeroes. That'd mean all the bits got zero-ed out, not just rearranged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
buf[offset] = htonl(c);
buf[4] = htonl(x);
buf[8] = htonl(y);
buf[12] = htonl(w);
```

this is broken. you should declare array of `int`egers. Reason is that `buf[i] = x` meants put a byte at i-th cell, and if it doesn't fit then truncate. That is what is happening.

Comment: Yep.  You'll need to make the same fix on the client side too.  Pay attention to those compiler warnings.

Comment: Sweet, can I just pass send(...) an int array? And would its length just be sizeof(int)*array_length?

Comment: @Rick, you still need to deal with endianness &c (yes, need), but yeah, `int buf[len]; /*...*/ send(sock,but,sizeof(int)*len,0);` should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
*((int *)(buf + offset)) = htonl(c);
*((int *)(buf + 4)) = htonl(x);
*((int *)(buf + 8)) = htonl(y);
*((int *)(buf + 12)) = htonl(w);
```

This is how you should have written the assignment snippet. This way you tell what 'buf + offset' is pointing to is a pointer to type 'int' and you would want to dereference now what this 'int *' is pointing to.

Simply assigning buf[x] = integer; translates to *((char *)(buf + x)) = integer. And since you are doing htonl(), I am taking a guess that your values c,x,y,w are such that they are < 65535  making the higher 32 bits 0 which is what is filled into buf when you do htonl(c/x/y/w).

HTH